# Css stack elements with the same left property

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to stack elements with the same left property:

DEMO:

```js
var genRandomLeft = function(){
    return (Math.random() * 100) + 1;
}

var generateDivs = function(count){
    var docElem = document.getElementById("container");
    var divs = "";
    for (var i=0; i<count; i++){
        divs += "<div style=\"left:"+genRandomLeft()+"%;\" class=\"marker\"></div>";
    }
    docElem.innerHTML = divs;
};

generateDivs(25);
```

```css
.marker{
    position: relative;
    width:35px;
    border:solid 1px;
    height:10px;
}
.container{
  width:100%;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

I would like to add to the css something like float:top in order to stack the items that share horizontal space. For example something like this:
[image: Expected behaviour]

Comment: Please give us a working demo of what you have now? And if this is just CSS, just give us rendered HTML/CSS, you can just post the HTML and CSS with a bunch of these generated elements.

Comment: @MichaelCoker added on edit

Comment: Can you please also give a static example (just a few divs) of your expected output? By comparing a static example against your dynamic output, you may also see what you need to change without our help. :)

Comment: @TheJim01 my mistake. I fixed it, but it is not the way I need them to behave,  I edited the answer and added a picture of the expected behaviour.

Comment: What is your definition of "horizontal space"? Are you talking about columns? (Doesn't seem to be the case due to vertical overlapping.) Are you talking about setting a pre-defined width, and forcing the items to wrap when their width + left positioning would send them past the limit? Like I said before, if you can manually create your desired effect, then you/we can probably figure out how to do it dynamically.

Comment: @TheJim01 Sorry, I can't make it work. That's why I posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

are you looking for something like `display:inline-block;` in the css for `.marker{}` ?

it doesnt take into account overlap, but it puts them onto the same horizontal plane